# Date , String , format java , android datepicker

Tags: java, android, string, date, date-format

I have a String which contains date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. 
For example `lastDate = "1/2/2012"` -> I get this date from date picker dialog.  Now I have  questions for this . I need to add 0 infront of date or month , if it is single digit . after the operation my date should be `20120201` ,any how I have done removing the delimeters and reversing the string , but I am stuck up , In adding 0 for day or month , if they are less than 10 , or single digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `DatePicker` then you get year, month and day as ints. So to build desired string you can use `String.format`:

```
String.format("%d%02d%02d", year, month, day);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use @NikitaBeloglazov method if you are using DatePicker. But in other situations, where you have a date as string, you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to do the parsing and formatting for you. For details and tutorial plz check http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-simpledateformat-class-formating-parsing-date-and-time/142